# Unable to extend EBS disk partition to use new space

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

Following the instructions at https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ebs-volume-size-increase/ I have successfully increased the size of my EBS volume in 3 of 4 supposedly identical instances. However, when I attempt the final instance I am receiving errors.

```
[ec2-user@ip-***-***-***-*** ~]$ lsblk
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1       259:0    0   8G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1   259:1    0   8G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p128 259:2    0   1M  0 part 

[ec2-user@ip-***-***-***-*** ~]$ lsblk -f
NAME          FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1                                                         
├─nvme0n1p1   ext4   /     ac513929-f93a-47d9-9637-9df68c0ca960 /
└─nvme0n1p128

[ec2-user@ip-***-***-***-*** ~]$ sudo growpart /dev/nvme0n1 1
NOCHANGE: disk=/dev/nvme0n1 partition=1: size=16773086, it cannot be grown
```

Does anyone know what's causing this or how it can be resolved? I've also tried skipping to the next step which obviously isn't working:

```
[ec2-user@ip-***-***-***-*** ~]$ sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1p1
resize2fs 1.43.5 (04-Aug-2017)
The filesystem is already 2096635 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

I've had a look around for similar issues but I'm not finding a lot with this specific error. I can confirm the disk is not optimising any more and is showing the correct new size in the console (32GB).

Comment: Is it the boot volume? Depending upon the AMI you are using, it might automatically resize the volume after a restart.

Comment: Ideally we would like to avoid restarting the instance since it's a production instance. It's a Ubuntu 16.04 AMI that we're going to migrate from but need a stop gap solution for the storage space while we do the migration work.